# Does Stackoverflow's code licensing override my previously specified license?

Tags: discussion, legal, licensing, mit-license

I heard recently that Stackoverflow has changed their license on code.  I don't know the details.  Myself, along with a handful of other users, have explicitly licensed code posted to Stackoverflow using a blurb in our profile (this particular blurb is a few years old at this point).  The license text reads as follows:

> Unless otherwise noted, all original source snippets I post on any StackExchange site are dedicated to the [public domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_Domain) and licensed under the terms of [the Unlicense](http://unlicense.org/) or [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/), whichever is most appropriate for your use. Do with them as you see fit, no attribution necessary. Please observe the license requirements of any third-party libraries or snippets that my code references (if any), as they may supersede this license.

Stackoverflow's license seems to be CC-BY-SA, which is more restrictive than the one I specified.  Either that or MIT?  I'm unsure on the details.

Which terms ought a user abide by?  What if I had specified a more restrictive license?

Comment: They haven't changed the license yet. They're still sorting out the change, if it's going to happen at all. So, it's still CC-BY-SA.

Comment: All content submitted under the previous licence will still be CC-BY-SA, and code submitted *after* the licence change will be under MIT.

Comment: @cybermonkey, note that the new license may not necessarily be MIT, as we don't know the details yet.

Comment: Note both licenses (old and most likely also the new one) are non-exclusive so you can dual(triple, quadruple, ...) license your own content any way you want (with other non-exclusive licenses and the user can then choose any of it to his liking.

Comment: Any code that you've licensed under CC0 and the Unlicense will continue to be licensed under those licenses. Stack Exchange also *adds* to that collection of licenses, but they are changing the license to the MIT. Nothing will change to the way you license your content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, it won't.**

To clarify this a bit: You can make your code available under whatever license you want, as you are doing now, *in addition to the standard CC-BY-SA licence which covers everything posted on Stack Overflow.*

This means that whoever uses your code can do so under either the standard Stack Exchange license (CC-BY-SA), *or* the licence(s) you specify.

In your case, the user can either use your code under the standard CC-BY-SA license covering all posts, which requires attribution, the Unilicense, *or* CC-0.

Saying that your code is licensed under a more restrictive license does not change this. Eg. If you say "All original code I post on Stack Overflow is licensed under the GPL" in your profile, people can use your code either under the GPL license, *or* use it under the standard SE CC-BY-SA license.

Essentially, everything you post is *always* licensed under CC-BY-SA, but you can choose to also make it available under another license. (It's yours after all, so you can license it under whatever license you want, and do whatever you want with it)

**So (how) will this change ?**

First, let me be clear: the new license has not been introduced yet. In fact, we don't even know what the final version will look like, if it ever does get introduced at all.

If Stack Exchange changes the license for posts, not much will change in your case.

Oder posts posted before the new license goes into effect will still be available under CC-BY-SA, as before. Newer posts will be licensed under the new license (Currently, this looks like it will be something MITish).

As before, you can choose to license your posts under whatever license you choose, *in* addition to the standard Stack Exchange license (CC-BY-SA for old posts, the new license for newer ones).

Comment: "It's yours after all, so you can license it under whatever license you want, and do whatever you want with it" - that actually only works because the license used by SO is a non-exclusive license. SO could, if they wanted to, decide to publish new content under a license that would indeed make the blurb of the original poster irrelevant (I guess). So the questions seems to be about a real concern.